# Query on group by and where clause, keeping null values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with following table:

Item, Product, Status

Status could be In Progress, Completed, Failed

I want three different tables, listing down number of items for a particular status for each product. I could do it with count on items, group by clause and where condition on the Status. And get something like:

For Item status = In Progress:

```
Product Items
A       10
B       20
```

and son on.

However, how do I preserve the product for which count(items)=0? If I put where condition, these products would get filtered out.

How can I get something like

```
Product Items
A       10
B       20
C       0
D       0
```

I am using Oracle SQL

Here's the query I use:

```
    select product, count(item) from item_main
where status = 'In Progress'
group by product;
```

Comment: can you show the original table as well?

Comment: The original table contains many more other columns, unfortunately I am not sure I can put it out here, as it's company data. But essentially, I simply want total number of items for each category, for each item status.

Comment: I updated my question with the query that I use. In this query, I am missing out category where count(item) = 0

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Product,
       COUNT( CASE status WHEN 'In Progress' THEN 1 END ) AS Items
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY Product
```

Comment: `select product as label,
      count(case STATUS where 'In Progress' then 1 else 0 end) as items,
      from item_main
      group by product;`  -- doesn't work.

Comment: Somehow throws error : missing right paranthesis. what am i missing here?

Comment: You have an extra comma in "`as items, from`" and you do not want the `else 0` part either omit it or use `else NULL` (since zero is countable but `NULL` is not).

Comment: Got it. 'when' , not 'where' :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.product, count(b.product) from 
(select product from item_main group by product) a LEFT JOIN item_main b on a.product = b.product 
where b.status = 'In progress'
```